# Checkbox styling in HeaderTemplate

Tags: asp.net, .net, css, checkbox

```
<asp:GridView AutoGenerateColumns="false" ID="gvFriend" runat="server" PageSize="5"
        AllowPaging="false" DataKeyNames="Email">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkhead" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" Text="Select All">
                    </asp:CheckBox>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
```

What's the best way to style this for the checkbox in the headertemplate?

Currently it is displayed as

```
[x] Select All
```

I want it to be

```
Select All
    [x]
```

Comment: You can just dont write in checkbox Text anything and add the word in <span> tag give it class and control it

Comment: Easier said than done. I am still learning CSS. Example?

Comment: :) okay i will make example to you

Comment: some thing like that http://jsfiddle.net/RQ62f/38/

Comment: to learn Css Just Use firebug in add-Ons in Fire Fox

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32830/discussion-between-mahmoude-elghandour-and-overule)

Comment: looks like it is not easy since you can't do it.

Comment: i updated link http://jsfiddle.net/RQ62f/44/

Comment: cheers... will let you know

Comment: did every thing work okay

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="warpper">
<span class="span">Select All</span>
<input id="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.span
{
display: block
}
.warpper {
border: 1px dotted firebrick;
text-align: center;
width: 80px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RQ62f/46/)